# Is there a grunt plugin that can download a directory from ftp?

Tags: ftp, gruntjs

I need to automate a task (via grunt) that downloads contents of one folder on a ftp server, and then uploads to another (folder or server - doesn't matter, both are plausable).

While there are several great plugins for deploying to ftp (doing the upload part), like grunt-ftpush, grunt-ftp-deploy, grunt-ftp-upload and grunt-ftpscript, I haven't been able to find one which performs the download part.

There a node module like https://nodejsmodules.org/pkg/ftp-get, but nothing for grunt.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue @harijs-deksnis?  I'm looking for the exact same thing...  while there are /plenty/ of push via ftp options, there are very few pull via ftp options for grunt.js.  Thanks!

Comment: No, but I haven't been looking lately. Perhaps something has appeared

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [grunt-curl](https://github.com/twolfson/grunt-curl). It has options for single files as well as directories.