# Is there a Grunt.js plugin for downloading via FTP?

Tags: node.js, ftp, gruntjs

There are **so many** plugins available which will help push to a webserver, but are there any that will download?

### A Bit of Background

I'd like to automate the process of publishing my CMS-based website.  The only issue is that our marketing people regularly blog and make content changes, so I'd like to first download the content files which have changed to my local development environment (`.md` files, which are not accessible from the web) before I push everything up to the staging server.

Does anything like this exist?  I've searched NPM quite thoroughly, as well as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690688/is-there-a-grunt-plugin-that-can-download-a-directory-from-ftp) which unfortunately didn't yield any results.

I did see a pretty robust cURL based plugin, however it doesn't support FTP authentication and since these files are not web-accessible directly, I'll need to leverage FTP.

Comment: Do you have other communication methods available, e.g. SSH? If so, you could use rsync or scp or sftp or something. There are at least plugins for rsync.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I only have FTP available to me (working on a very opinionated server unfortunately) so I'll need something via FTP.

I'm beginning to read resources in regards to how to write this myself - would be my first plugin, but it would save me loads of time.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search gave me this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ftp

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I tried this plugin and had to uninstall it after about two hours and many obscenities.  Unfortunately it's poorly documented and doesn't look well-maintained.